# ADODB.Stream ReadText error

Tags: asp-classic

I am using a downloaded pure ASP script to upload files. My form contains a textarea and a file upload component. It works fine when I enter regular text but it cannot handle when I copy and paste something from word having special characters. The error I am getting is:

Provider error '80070057'

The parameter is incorrect.

/forum/freeaspupload.asp, line 309

The part of my code which throws the error is:

```
Private Function ConvertUtf8BytesToString(start, length)    
    StreamRequest.Position = 0

    Dim objStream
    Dim strTmp

    ' init stream
    Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
    objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open

    ' write bytes into stream
    StreamRequest.Position = start+1
    StreamRequest.CopyTo objStream, length
    objStream.Flush

    ' rewind stream and read text
    objStream.Position = 0
    objStream.Type = adTypeText
    strTmp = objStream.ReadText

    ' close up and return
    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing
    ConvertUtf8BytesToString = strTmp   
End Function
```

Line 309 is the line:

```
strTmp = objStream.ReadText
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old question but since there is no answer and I got the exact same problem and finally found a solution, I think it can be good to share it.

The problem is related to IIS version since it was working fine on IIS6 but stop to work when we moved to IIS8.5

See [ReadText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678077(v=vs.85).aspx)

By defaut ReadText parameter is -1 (adReadAll).

For some reason, this default parameter seems not working with IIS8.5. You have to put the length of the text that you want to read.

so ReadText(2000) will work fine.

Of course, you will have to figured out the maximum length or find a way to loop and read everything

By MSFT :

> If NumChar is more than the number of characters left in the stream, only the characters remaining are returned. The string read is not padded to match the length specified by NumChar. If there are no characters left to read, a variant whose value is null is returned. ReadText cannot be used to read backwards.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Honestly I don't remember in which project I faced this problem or what I finally did for this but hope your solution will be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I get my data. I just write "ReadText" twice :)

```
strData = objStream.ReadText(1) // return first char
strData = strData & objStream.ReadText(-1) // returm full text
```